# Usar un archivo .jar ofuscado como librería de otro proyecto

Tags: android-studio, jar, ofuscación

He creado una librería `.jar` en `android studio` para que otros puedan usar funcionalidades  de un API REST que tengo montado de forma sencilla. La idea es pasar este archivo `.jar` a terceros para que hagan una serie de llamadas pasando los datos necesarios y este se gestione sólo.

**¿Que problema tengo?**

El problema es que no quiero que este código sea legible por el usuario (a sabiendas que con ingenieria inversa se puede sacar todo) y no sé cómo puedo ofuscar el código de manera que permita al usuario acceder a las funciones de dentro.

**¿Que he intentado?**

He usado el ejecutable de `proguard` de `android studio` para ofuscar el código del `.jar` obteniendo el resultado esperado, pero al importarlo a otro proyecto no he sido capaz de acceder a las clases de esta.

Por ejemplo lo que en en el jar sin ofuscar sería : `miapp.libreria.functiones`, en el jar ofuscado es `a.a.a`.

También he intentado no ofuscar los packages para que los nombres no cambiasen pero no lo he conseguido.

Cualquier ayuda tanto para hacerlo de la manera que lo he intentado como para hacerlo de cualquier otra forma es bienvenido.